# psycopg2 INSERT INTO execute not returning result

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am inserting an item the usual way using cursor's execute. However, doing a `cursor.fetchone()` afterwards throws a `ProgrammaticError` saying no results could be fetched. I can see the item inserted into the database.

What is the issue here? I am opening a connection with a `with` statement, and I am not calling `commit` as this is taken care of in the `with` statement.

Is there a way to retrieve the result that was just inserted into `psycopg2` easily?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you didn't add a `RETURNING *;` to your `INSERT` statement.

So... try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table
...
RETURNING *;
```